# Tree Shaking in a CRA Monorepo

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, bundling-and-minification, tree-shaking, craco

I have a monorepo yarn workspaces project that contains a create-react-app application and a UI library.

In my `@app/ui` packages, inside the `src` folder, I have a the following files:

`country.ts`

```js
interface Country {
  name: string;
  alpha2: string;
  alpha3: string;
  subregion: string;
}

export const countries: Record<string, Country> = {
  NZ: {
    name: 'New Zealand',
    alpha2: 'NZ',
    alpha3: 'NZL',
    subregion: 'Australia and New Zealand'
  },
};
```

`index.ts`

```js
export * from countries.ts;
```

...as well as other files that are exported from `index.ts` above. Even though my `@app/cra` application has `@app/ui` as a dependency, and has the following line of code in one of its files:

`import { MyComponent } from @app/ui`

I never actually import anything from `countries.ts`. I use craco to be able to include the external UI package in the `react-scripts` build of the CRA by overriding the configuration to include the external folders using `babel-loader`.

However, when I build the CRA app for production and use source maps analyzer to examine the bundles resulting from the build, I always find `countries` in there. Why is it not tree shaken?